# AngularJS: How to use a callback in a component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is this code. It is necessary to make a call `onFinish` and pass there the parameters timer and `$$endTime`. But when I make a call to `$ctrl.onFinish(parameter)`, I get this exception:

> TypeError error occurs: $ctrl.onFinish is not a function

How to correctly implement a callback call?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   var $ctrl = this;

    $ctrl.$onInit = function() {    
     $ctrl.timerId = 0;
        $ctrl.timers = [];
        $ctrl.addTimer(10);
        $ctrl.addTimer(3);          
    }

    $ctrl.addTimer = function(seconds) {
        $ctrl.timers.push({
          id: this.timerId++,
          seconds: seconds*100
        });  
        $ctrl.startTimer($ctrl.timers[$ctrl.timers.length - 1]);
    }
    
    $ctrl.startTimer = function(timer) {
     var i = setInterval(() => {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                timer.seconds -= 1; 
                if (timer.seconds == 0) {
                    $ctrl.end();
                    clearInterval(i);
                }
            })
        }, 1)
    }

        
    $ctrl.end = function() {
        $ctrl.onFinish({
            timer: {
               id: 1
            },
            $endTime: '123124'
        });
    }
    
    $ctrl.myFunction = (timer, $endTime) => {
     $ctrl.status = 'Timer ' + timer.id + ' finished at ' + $endTime
    }

    $ctrl.removeTimer = function(index){
        $ctrl.timers.splice(index, 1);
    }
}).component('myTimer', {
    controller: 'MyCtrl',
    bindings: {
        startSeconds: '<',
        onFinish: '&',
    },
    template: `<span >{{$ctrl.startSeconds}}</span>`,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as myCtrl">
  <div>
    Status: {{status ? status : 'Waiting...'}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <button ng-click="myCtrl.addTimer(5)">Add timer</button>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="timer in myCtrl.timers">
    <div>
      <h3>Timer {{::timer.id}}</h3>
      <button ng-click="myCtrl.removeTimer($index)">X</button>
      <my-timer start-seconds="timer.seconds"
                on-finish="myFunction(timer, $endTime)">
      </my-timer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you didn't set the controller of your component

Comment: @Groben fix.but one error is stil remains =(

Comment: What is the error ? Is it the same ?

Comment: @Groben TypeError: $ctrl.onFinish is not a function

Comment: Can you add the code where you use your component ? <my-timer></my-timer>

Comment: @Groben i have added html code in my question

Comment: The code uses the same controller for both the component and the main app. Re-factor the design to use separate controllers. `$ctrl.onFinish` is not a function in the main app because nothing is bound to it. Also use the `$interval` service instead of `setInterval`. There are several other bugs in the code as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code is unsalvageable. It needs to be re-factored and multiple bugs removed. The question is not useful to other readers.

Answer (score -1):

The error was quite explicit:

> $ctrl.onFinish is not a function

It is indeed, not a function. To fix it, you should use your component like that:

```
<my-timer start-seconds="timer.seconds" on-finish="myFunction(timer, $endTime)"></my-timer>
```

and in your corresponding controller:

```
$ctrl.myFunction = function(timer, $endTime){
    $ctrl.status = 'Timer ' + timer.id + ' finished at ' + $endTime
}
```

Note that your `onEnd` function should use the `onFinish` like this:

```
$ctrl.onEnd = function () {
    $ctrl.onFinish({
        timer: {
            id: 1
        },
        $endTime: '123124'
    });
}
```

Comment: $ctrl.myFunction should go in the parent controller not the component controller

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
 onFinish: '&' --> onFinish: '='
```

Oh I'm sorry, the error in line

```
$ctrl.end = function() {
    $ctrl.onFinish({
        timer: { id: 1 },
        $endTime: '123124'
    });
 }
```

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, the error in line <code>$ctrl.end = function() {
      $ctrl.onFinish({
        timer: {
            id: 1
        },
        $endTime: '123124'
    });
    }</code>